# Rails: How to validate uniqueness of an attribute only within a one-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a relationship similar to this:

```
class Cat
  belongs_to :owner
end

class Owner
  has_many :cats
end
```

I would like each `Cat` that belongs to an `Owner` to have a unique name. For example, Bob and John (two owners) can both own a cat named Bill, however John cannot own two cats named Bill.

I've tried `validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: owner_id }` on my Cat model, as well as `scope: owner` but I'm running into this error: `NameError: undefined local variable or method owner_id for #<Class:0x000000073578f0>`. The second I comment out my `validates` statement, calling cat_instance.owner_id returns the proper id.

Comment: I guess you are missing `:` before `owner_id` in your validation statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

You should pass a symbol to the scope option:

```
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :owner_id }
```

Comment: Thanks. Let's say a Cat `has_one :pet, class_name: "Cat", foreign_key: "pet_id"`, how would I make the name be unique on the Cat level immediately under Owner **only** i.e from the previous example, Bob can only own one Cat named Bill, but Bill can have a Cat named Bill as well?

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understood your requirement, but you can pass multiple attributes to the scope property, something like: `uniqueness: { scope: [:owner_id, :pet_id] }`, I think that might work

Answer (score 1):

```
class Owner
  has_many :cats
  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :owner_id }
end
```